# Create Player class/variable for blackjack

Tags: java, draw, blackjack

Relatively new to `Java`, and I love it so far, but am stuck on an assignment. I have to create a **blackjack game**, (I've gone through multiple Google searches already) and am having trouble with creating a Player1 and Player2. I created the card `class` already. I need to deal a card to player one, ask him/her if they would like another (I have the loop for that), and add the cards together. Same for Player2. This is where I am stuck, my Card Class includes a `draw()` which should deal out the cards.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game
{



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int Player1 = 0, Sum1, Player2 = 0, Sum2;//Sums used to keep running total of cards Players have

        Card[] cards = new Cards[52];




       }

    //sample of loop I would use to ask if they would like another card
    do
    {


    System.out.println("Would you like to draw another card?");
    answer = input.nextLine();


    }while(answer.equals("Yes"));


    }

    //Card class with draw() at the bottom
        class Card{ 

    private int Spades = 0, Hearts = 1, Diamonds = 2, Clubs = 3;

    private int Ace = 1, Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13;


        private int face_value;

        public Card(){
            face_value = 1;
    }
    public void setFacevalue(int value){

        face_value = value;
    }
    public int getFacevalue(){

            return face_value;
    }
    public int draw(){

        Random ran = new Random();
            face_value = ran.nextInt(13)+1;
        return face_value;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Be bold - show us your code!  It's a bit tricky to answer otherwise.

Comment: You could also think through your problem a bit more and ask a more specific question -- being stuck is no shame, nor is being a beginner, but it is difficult to know what you need help with unless you tell us.

Comment: I guess what I need help with is dealing the card to each player, and adding said cards together in a running total. I believe I can do the rest on my own. (fingers crossed).

Comment: I'm with @arcy here -- you need to spend more time thinking through your design. If a card doesn't draw itself, why does it implement the draw() method? Doesn't a player draw a card from a deck? Doesn't that mean that player needs a way to call a draw() method on deck, which passes a new card from the deck to the player? Don't get caught up in the details of the language -- if you don't fully understand the problem, you'll never be able to answer correctly.

Comment: `Card[] cards = new Cards[52];`???

Comment: Ok, I understand what you guys are saying and it makes sense. I need to deal the first card to player1, then ask if they would like another card, (which I can do with a loop). Same for player2. I'm just stuck on the dealing aspect of it. Sorry for the muddled statements before.

Comment: I think I got it! Man that is a great feeling. My teacher is one of the best I have ever had and the best CS teacher at my college, but English is his second language, so it can get kinda sticky with the assignments. Thanks guys, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, it is customary to upvote it; if it answered your original question, it is customer to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One would think the class Card would represent one card, and therefore would not have a method dealing with a deck of cards.  There is no good way for one card to know how many cards are in the deck, etc., without giving the single card a reference to the deck, which is counterintuitive.

I'd say you have cause for a Deck class, containing some number of cards.  I would think your Card class would allow for both a name (jack, queen, 10) and a value in this game (all of those are 10).

Then perhaps your main (in a class called Dealer?) calls a method on Deck to get a random card, and calls a method on Player to give them that card, rotating through the players in the game (there might be more than 2 someday) until everyone has the initial 2 cards.  Then the first Player can look at the total of all the cards he has and decide whether he wants another, until he's busted or stops, etc.  It seems fitting that your Player class has the logic to determine at what point he stops taking additional cards.

I hope that's enough help.  Have fun.